# $('#dlg').dialog('close') is not working with simple JSP page

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-easyui

`$('#dlg').dialog('close')` is not clickable, while on save button alert is coming. The answer on StackOverflow is related to an iframe. It does not work in my case.

```
<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" title="Complex Toolbar on Dialog" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; padding: 10px" data-options="iconCls: 'icon-save', buttons: '#dlg-buttons'">
  The dialog content.
</div>
<div id="dlg-buttons">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="javascript:alert('save')">Save</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Close</a>
</div>
```

On click of close, dialog window should get close.

Comment: Do you get any errors from the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at _23f (jquery.easyui.min.js:3162)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easyui.min.js:3377)
    at Function.each (1.11.2.jquery.min.js:142)
    at m.fn.init.each (1.11.2.jquery.min.js:42)
    at Object.close (jquery.easyui.min.js:3376)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.panel (jquery.easyui.min.js:3330)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.window (jquery.easyui.min.js:3732)
    at m.fn.init.$.fn.dialog (jquery.easyui.min.js:3890)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (urlTagAction.action?ENTITY=enty&MODE=sp&PAGE=form&WEB_ID=:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the console, you should have some error like "*cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'*"

Simple fix for this is:

```
$('#dlg').dialog().dialog('close');
```

Demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" title="Complex Toolbar on Dialog" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; padding: 10px" data-options="iconCls: 'icon-save', buttons: '#dlg-buttons'">
  The dialog content.
</div>
<div id="dlg-buttons">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="javascript:alert('save')">Save</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog().dialog('close');">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working good, but each time i'll have to click twice this i want to avoid,  how to do this.

Comment: Can you create a demo https://jsfiddle.net or in main post so that I can check the issue?